# Database not update when using apache camel sql component

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to use apache camel (sql component) to update the DB. Problem is that the DB just doesn't get updated. The sql:update is working fine when i hard code the query, but when i try to use ${body[0][id]} it doesn't update required field. Any feedback on what might be going wrong?

```
from("direct:updateSql")
.to("sql:select * from mytable limit 1")
.log("update mytable set status = '100' where id = '${body[0][id]}'")
.to("sql:update mytable set status = '100' where id = '${body[0][id]}'")
.end();
```

Note that status and id are integer fields but if i remove the ' from the .to() then i throws some errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs you must use `:#` as the placeholder syntax

- http://camel.apache.org/sql-component

So try with

```
.to("sql:update mytable set status = 100 where id = :#${body[0][id]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked too.

```
from("direct:updateSql")
.to("sql:select * from mytable limit 1")
.setHeader("id", simple("${body[0][id]}"))
.to("sql:update mytable set status_id = 100 where id = :#id")
.end();
```